# <algorithm> sort custom condition

Tags: c++, sorting, stl-algorithm

Okay, so I've tried to use sort to vector of items so the size of two adjecant items is <= 2d.
So here's my attempt:

```
struct item{
    long number;
    long size;
};

// d is global variable.
bool check(const item& x, const item& y)
{
    return ((x.size + y.size) <= (2 * d));
}

// Items is a vector of item.
sort(items.begin(), items.end(), check);
```

What am I doing wrong or it's even impossible to sort using condition like that ?

Comment: 1. What error are you getting (if any?)  2. Sort functions generally have integer return values, since they need at least three conditions: A < B, A > B, A == B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's even impossible to sort using condition like that ?

No. The comparer in [`sort`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) must satisfy the criteria of a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) which yours clearly doesn’t (for instance it’s not irreflexive).

Answer (score 2):

This problem cannot be solved in O(N log N) time. I don't know if it's NP-hard, but it's quite non-trivial. I do think it's safe to say that a program solving the problem as expressed in your code would require exponential time. There are such programs: I think it could be fiddled around and plugged into a linear optimizer.

No standard library function will get you even most of the way to a general solution. There are no standard library functions slower than O(N log N), and none solve problems that may be intractable.

This problem is intractable if, for example, every `size` equals `10 * d`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the sort() method wrong.

STL sort is used to order a list of elements. For an 'ordering', you need to satisfy conditions like:

1. if check( A, B ) == false AND A != B, then check( B, A ) returns true.
2. if check( A, B ) == false AND check( B, C) == false AND A, B, C are distinct, then check ( A, C ) returns false.

A good idea for where you can use STL's sort() is, given your list of items S and the order you want the items to be in:

1. If the order of the items in S changes, the output order should remain the same.
2. The output is unique.
3. All the items in the output order have some relation that is a [strict partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_ordering) relation.

If this is the case, then you probably can write the check function to work for you :)

Comment: The second condition should actually be : if (check(A,B) == true and check(B,C) == true then check(A,C) == true. (This is the _transitive_ requirement; condition one is the _asymmetric_ requirement)